# During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST, when persisting an entity

Tags: java, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

I am using EclipseLink with Glassfish 5.1 and I have these four entities:

```
public class AppUser implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "consumer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<CustomerOrder> orders;
}
public class LineItem implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne
    private Part part;
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name="ORDERID")
    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private CustomerOrder order;
}
public class CustomerOrder implements Serializable {
    @NotNull
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<LineItem> lineItems;
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name="CONSUMERID")
    @ManyToOne
    private AppUser consumer;
}
public class Part implements Serializable {
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    private String manufacture;
    @NotNull
    private String number;
    @NotNull
    private String description;
    @NotNull
    private double price;
}
```

At the server startup, I have a singleton object that loads the database with some initial test data from an XML file. The idea is that "Part" must be present in the database so the AppUser can order it. First, the "Part" entity gets loaded without any errors. Then one record for "AppUser" entity with its associated mapped entities (CustomerOrder and LineItem), gets loaded, which fails with the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: org.me.mavenlistservicedb.entity.Part@7f354d11.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.discoverUnregisteredNewObjects(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.calculateChanges(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:770)
    at ................
.............................
```

Here is the test data I am loading for the AppUser from the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<users>
    <user>
        <firstName>Joseph</firstName>
        <orders>
            <status>Pending Shipment</status>
            <lastUpdated>2021-03-04T22:25:23.751+03:30</lastUpdated>
            <Parts>
                <lineitem>
                    <quantity>2</quantity>
                    <part>
                        <name>Break Caliper</name>
                        <manufacture>Halt At Will Inc.</manufacture>
                        <number>BC774091HA</number>
                        <description>Disk break pads</description>
                        <price>35.95</price>
                    </part>
                </lineitem>
            </Parts>
            <total>71.9</total>
            <orderNumber>OTTaviano234576907</orderNumber>
        </orders>
    </user>
</users>
```

If I add a cascade type of "persist" on the @OneToOne mapping between "LineItem" and "Part" the exception doesn't occur but more than one "AppUser" record gets loaded into the database. How can I fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: Why does the Part Class definition not show JPA entity mappings? The problem is related to the Part reference being set somewhere to point at an instance that wasn't apart of the the context it is being associated to, but tracking down where that is might be a challenge. Can you debug where this Part@7f354d11 instance was created and came from in a debugger?

Comment: Hello Chirs, thanks for the comment. More I think about your question, the more I suspect about the content of the XML file. Regarding your question, a large list of Part entities gets loaded into DB by the singleton. Later, the app reads the XML file shown in the post, it then creates instances of AppUser, CustomerOrder, LineItem, Part and it tries to Persist. The AppUser and CustomerOrder have bidirectional mappings, the CustomerOrder and LineItem also have bidirectional mapping while I want unidirectional mapping between LineItem and Part.......

Comment: where Part should not know anything about LineItem. Given this scenario, is the mapping between LineItem and Part correct?  If not what should be the mapping relationship?

Comment: The mapping setup is fine for what you described. If these Part instances already exist, and you are using a singleton to hold the Part instance in memory instead of pulling it from the DB/EntityManager context when creating new LineItem instances, you might want to add another mapping to LineItem - a basic mapping to the foreign key field that points to Part. You would make this writable, and then set the OneToOne mapping as insertable=false, updatable=false. You then only need to set the foreign key value with the ID from the part. There are some challenges with this, mostly to a cache

Comment: Thanks, let me try it and I will let you know tomorrow

Comment: Chris, my hard drive crashed and I lost all my data and my backup is 12 days old, so I will try your recommendation, once I recover the lost data.

Comment: Hello Chris, Thanks for guiding me through. I recovered my system and the code works fine now. Decide which comment you want to make as an answer and I will accept.